# Strange Graphical Behavior

Tags: 14.04, graphics, window-manager

(This is xposted from ubuntu official forum. Nobody answered there, i hope i will be more lucky here)

Since when I have installed xubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on my new laptop I got this strange behavior that you can see in these screens (the black bars are inserted to remove private data, the screens otherwise represent what I actually see on my desktop):

- [Text disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORgLz.jpg) (sorry for the crappy quality, but it was taken by my mobile camera)
- [Odd windows behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaQyQ.png) (In this pic the central windows was supposed to be a terminal :/)

It happens when I log in, without any specific action on my side, and the problem intensifies when I use the browser or when many windows are opened at the same time.

Here's my laptop's specifications:

- Acer aspire V15 (code V3-572G-75CA)
- intel core i7 5500U 2.4GHz
- Nvidia GeForce 840M 2GB VRAM
- 8GB DDR3
- 1000 GB HDD

Here's what i get from lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U     Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

Here are the -v -s details of the graphic devices:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0940
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 69
Memory at c2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: i915

04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0942
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
Memory at c3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
Capabilities: [900] #19
```

I also got these strange messages in dmsg that are worth reporting:

```
[   11.359540] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   11.359591] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[   11.359607] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   11.359608] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[   11.383686] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   11.383759] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input12
[   11.383891] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   11.383898] ACPI: Video Device [PXSX] (multi-head: yes  rom: yes  post: no)
[   11.383929] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:52/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input13
[   11.383991] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[   11.384356] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 70 for MSI/MSI-X
[   11.393858] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input14
[   11.393923] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input15
[   11.393980] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input16
[   11.116752] VGA switcheroo: detected Optimus DSM method \_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX handle
[   11.116774] checking generic (d0000000 410000) vs hw (b0000000 10000000)
[   11.116776] checking generic (d0000000 410000) vs hw (c0000000 2000000)
[   11.116805] nouveau 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0106 -> 0107)
[   11.117047] nouveau ![  DEVICE][0000:04:00.0] unknown Maxwell chipset
[   11.117051] nouveau E[  DEVICE][0000:04:00.0] unknown chipset, 0x118010a2
[   11.117053] nouveau E[     DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22
[   11.117273] nouveau: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -22
[   11.117658] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[   11.118163] input: Acer BMA150 accelerometer as /devices/virtual/input/input8
[   11.125464] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 4096M
[   11.125468] checking generic (d0000000 410000) vs hw (d0000000 10000000)
[   11.125469] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[   11.125482] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[   11.125545] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[   11.126214] [drm] ACPI BIOS requests an excessive sleep of 10000 ms, using 1500 ms instead
[   11.146760] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 69 for MSI/MSI-X
[   11.146771] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   11.146773] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   11.146802] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[   11.187004] [drm] VBT doesn't support DRRS
```